# 100% height android listview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am just starting to develop android apps. I have a layout question. I want to create the main screen for my app. It is a menu with 7 options, each options would be an icon at the left, a short text and a check at the left (on/off component).

I have written it in a list view element, I have created a simple adapter with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_io"/>

       <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:singleLine="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu will have always 7 options, I would like that the listview filled the height of the screen. Each element with the same height. Is it possible that with listview? Or, perhaps would be better making the menu out of a list view?

I have been reading about linear layout and the weight property. Please, could you help me? It is my first layout, I would thank any advice aboput layout I should use.

Thanks a lot, best regards!

P.D: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Linearlayout and inside i put all the items to be displayed...

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Texto"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Texto"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Repeat the item five times more -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is better than using a listview. Thanks!

Comment: I hope my answer help you :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want all the items to be displayed (without a scroll) then there's no use in a `ListView`. use a `LinearLayout` instead and set the layout_weight of each menu item to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not sure, I agree with you, ListView is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the others guys said is better use the LinearLayout. And like you mentioned you can use weight attribute too.

> **Equally weighted children**
>
> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".

As you are trying to implement a Menu, I think the best approach is substitute each RelativeLayout(with textview and imageview) for a button. So, your layout will be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="7.0" > //Defines the maximum weight sum


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Option 1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon1"
    android:onClick="handleOption"/> // method to handle onClick

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Option 2"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon2"
    android:onClick="handleOption"/> // method to handle onClick

    //Add more five buttons
    .
    .
    .
```

In your activity, you should load this layout, using `setContentView()` and you must implement a method `handleOption` like below to handle `onClick` event of each button.

```
 public view handleOption(View view)
 {
     switch(view.getId()) ....
 }
```

In that way, you do not need implement onClickListener Interface, have one method to each button and set the onClickListener for each button.

Comment: Thanks. I want icon left, text at center and a button on/off at the left. I don´t know if with button I can put three elements. Thanks again, I will try!

Comment: You can use just a ToogleButton (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html). Similar a button, you can set a text, drawableLeft and it comes with on/off already implemented.